# How to set the column width of the desc result in sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is there any way to set the column width of the result of `desc` command in sqlplus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format sqlplus reports in a [variety of ways](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm).

What you need here can be mostly achieved by `[SET LIN[ESIZE][2]]` (you have to scroll down)

Comment: Even though this doesn't have the most upvotes, it actually does solve the problem of the `Name` column being unnecessarily wide.  It's confusing for users since for "regular" query results the column widths are changed with `column Name width A30` but in the case of `desc` it has no effect.

Answer (score 4):

In general you can't. Describe decides how much horizontal space to take up based on linesize. I [asked Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3346426700346395529) about how to set the describe width and linesize seperately. Some of the follow up answers have scripts to capture current linesize, change to a shorter linesize to keep the describe results compact, and then restore current linesize.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need `SET LINES XX`

However this handy SQL*plus command reference will help :-)

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html